# jsonix properties - ogc-schemas .js aren't same

Tags: jsonix

The manual on jsonix properties at https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Properties shows properties as being something like:

```
name: 'MyModule',
    typeInfos: [{
        type: 'classInfo',
        localName: 'InputType',
        propertyInfos: [{
            type: 'attribute',
            typeInfo: 'Boolean',
            name: 'checked'
        }]
    }],
```

But then (after `npm install ogc-schemas`) what I am seeing is:

```
    ln: 'TimeClockPropertyType',
    ps: [{
        n: 'timeClock',
        rq: true,
        en: 'TimeClock',
        ti: '.TimeClockType'
      },
```

With the abbreviated names.

Which should it be and why doesn't it matter if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

This is what's called [compact naming](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Compact-Naming). This is an [option](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) of the [Jsonix Schema Compiler](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler) which generates shorter names in mappings, like `n` instead of `name` or `dens` instead of `defaultElementNamespaceURI`. The goal is clearly to make mappings smaller and since [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) are pretty large, they are compiled with compact naming by default.

If you want standard naming, fork and remove

```
<arg>-Xjsonix-compact</arg>
```

from all the `pom.xml`s.

Both compact and standard names work in runtime, I think standard names have higher priority.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I'm debugging so the long names are helpful.  Though I get your reason for being compact.